# Why the make error was occurred when openssl building

Tags: openssl, build-error

I want to build the openssl.

I have configured with the option "-enable-static --disable-shared".

```
./Configure -enable-static --disable-shared
```

And After make, error was occurred like the following.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/andykim/Project/tools/openssl_tool/openssl-3.1.4'
gcc  -I. -Iinclude -Iapps/include  -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -enable-static 
--disable-shared -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" 
-DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib64/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib64/ossl-modules\"" 
-DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.d.tmp 
-MT apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o -c -o apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o apps/lib/app_libctx.c
cc1: error: unknown pass shared specified in -fdisable
Makefile:4329: recipe for target 'apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/andykim/Project/tools/openssl_tool/openssl-3.1.4'
Makefile:3295: recipe for target 'build_sw' failed
make: *** [build_sw] Error 2
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks